# Duplicação conteúdo PHP

Tags: html, css

Quando duplico este código, ele aparece alinhado na vertical, gostaria de alinhar este código na horizontal

```
<?php 

for($k=0;$k<count($items);$k++)
{
    $item = $items[$k];
    $expire_key = (isset($from_recv) ? $from_recv : 0).'|'.ltrim($item['id'],0);
    $barcode = $item['id'];
    $text = $item['name'];

    if(isset($items_expire[$expire_key]) && $items_expire[$expire_key])
    {
        $text.= " (".lang('common_expire_date').' '.$items_expire[$expire_key].')';     
    }
    elseif (isset($from_recv))
    {
        $text.= " (RECV $from_recv)";
    }

    $page_break_after = ($k == count($items) -1) ? 'auto' : 'always';
    echo "<div class='barcode-label' style='page-break-after: $page_break_after'>".$company."<br /><img style='vertical-align:baseline;'src='".site_url('barcode').'?barcode='.rawurlencode($barcode).'&text='.rawurlencode($barcode)."&scale=$scale' /><br />".$text."</div>";


}


?>
```

Comment: Olá Mateus. Sua pergunta não é relacionada com PHP, mas sim com o HTML e o CSS gerado. Editei as tags da sua pergunta. Para ter uma resposta mais facilmente sugiro postar o HTML gerado por esse código.

Comment: Qual a diferença para esta pergunta? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227584/5878

Comment: Também me parece que é uma pergunta repetida, apenas redigida de forma diferente.

Comment: Seria bacana se colocasse pelo menos um print da tela de resultados para termos uma noção melhor, tentar resolver assim a olho nu fica difícil de solucionar a questão.